# How to call dockerfile inside folder with jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, deployment, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, repository

I am in deploy any aplications with metod ci/cd jenkins...i pull image from git repository and dockerfile insider folder, for example repository `thismyapp/dashboard/dockerfile`.
in my habit, the dockerfile in `thismyapp/dockerfile`. so i call dockerfile with

```
sh 'docker build -t image_name:image_tag -f . /dockerfile .'
```

in my new case, what way i call dockerfile insider folder?

thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the current working directory you can simply follow one of the options below.

```
 dir('thismyapp/dashboard') {
      sh 'docker build -t image_name:image_tag -f . /dockerfile .'
    }
```

**OR**

```
sh """
cd thismyapp/dashboard
docker build -t image_name:image_tag -f . /dockerfile .
"""
```